# xhr async багается и делает кучу циклов или возращает xhr.readyState = 0

Tags: chrome-extension, xhr

Мне нужно получить данные с 6 сайтов в асинхронном режиме (т.к. в синхронном слишком медленно) и обработать их в функции start() Но обработчику нужны все данные сразу, поэтому сделал промежуточную функцию run() которая сохраняет данные с сайтов и когда все получены запускает start(). Проблема в том что данные в данном коде приходят только с csmoney, а в полном коде приходят кучу раз с csmoney и 1 раз с другого сайта, а остальные 4 сайта будто молчат, хотя судя по отладке chrome во вкладке network, данные приходят корректно.

```
var pjar;
var ploot;
var pcsmoney;

function loot(){
    var url = "https://loot.farm/fullprice.json";
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState != 4){
            return;
        } else if(xhr.responseText){
            console.log('loot');
            run('loot',JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        };
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};

function skinsjar(){
    var url = "https://skinsjar.com/api/v3/load/bots?refresh=0&v=2";
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState != 4){
            return;
        } else if(xhr.responseText){
            console.log('jar');
            run('jar',JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)['items']);
        };
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};

function csmoney(){
    var url = "https://cs.money/load_bots_inventory";
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState != 4){
            return;
        } else if(xhr.responseText){
            console.log('csmoney');
            run('csmoney',JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)['items']);
        };
    };
    xhr.send(null);
};

function run(name, data){
    switch(name) {
        case 'jar': pjar = data; break;
        case 'csmoney': pcsmoney = data; break;
        case 'loot': ploot = data; break;
    };
    if(pjar && pcsmoney && ploot){
        console.log('Стартуем!');
        start();
    };
};

function start(){
    // Обработка всех массивов полученных данных.
};

loot();
skinsjar();
csmoney();
```

Все это работает в расширении хрома, но должно на данной стадии работать и без расширения.

Comment: Сделал через $.ajax и вроде как норм, только вот как мне из success функции вызвать add()? Он ее от туда не видит.

Comment: обработчик события обычно вешают до отправки запроса. Поменяй местами `xhr.send` и `xhr.onreadystatechage`

Comment: Поменял. Все равно не как надо делает все. Запустил (1 x bot; 15 x csmoney) потом еще запустил (1 x bot; 6 x csmoney) еще запустил (1 x bot; 10 x csmoney). До этого запускал еще было (1 x bot; 15 x tradeskins). То есть при 1 самом запуске вообще csmoney даже не выдал. При 2 tradeskins не выдал и кучу csmoney. А loot, swap и jar ни разу вообще не выдается. (все это названия сайтов)

Comment: Ничего не понял из твоего комментария. Что ты вообще делаешь и как?

Comment: Если xhr.readyState = 4 и xhr.responseText не пуст, то я вывожу в консоль название сайта который спарсил и запускаю функцию add() и вот выше написал сколько раз названия выводятся. То есть какие-то сайты вообще не выводятся, а какие-то много раз, и при этом постоянно цифра меняется.

Comment: что за функция `add`? имелась ввиду `run`? Как именно ты запускаешь? Сколько раз?

Comment: Да, run(); Эта функция сохраняет полученный данные в переменные и запускает функцию start(); после того как все 6 сайтов спарсены. т.к. start(); требует все данные сразу. Запускаю 1 раз когда сайт загружается, но на деле как видно где-то не запускается, где-то много раз. При этом делал без async все идеально работало, но слишком медленно, задумываюсь об оптимизации, т.к. дальше надо будет еще 6 сайтов парсить.

Comment: без [mcve] вряд ли что-то можно сказать.

Comment: Хватит 3 сайта? Или все 6 делать? (Вопрос обновил)

Comment: Вполне хватит. За исключением того, что будет работать cors и будет проблема с запросами на сторонние домены код вполне рабочий

Comment: Код может выполняться с любого домена, т.к. это расширение) Попробую $.ajax, он у меня работал норм, только не понял как данные в функцию передать.

Comment: Это было к _должно на данной стадии работать и без расширения_. Приведенный пример кода, в общих чертах, выглядит рабочим и не должен вызывать нескольких обращений, если только что-то подобное не вызывается в самом старте. Вместо XMLHttpRequest можно посмотреть в сторону `fetch`, который возвращает Promise, в его случае следить за выполнением намного проще

Comment: даже передавать ничего не надо, в своих функциях оставляешь только вызов `fetch`, например, `function loot(){ return fetch('https://loot.farm/fullprice.json').then(response=>response.json());}`. В месте вызова функций складываешь результат в массив, который передаешь в `Promise.all`: `Promise.all([loot(), skinsjar()]).then(results=> start(results))`

Comment: 1 проблемка, 1 из сайтов требует отправки Form Data. Просто сделать {body: "данные"} не прокатит. На xhr я отправлял xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); тут чет не пойму как их отправить, headers: ['Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'] не работает, с {} скобками тоже.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73036/discussion-between-grundy-and-mr-lucky-tomas).